# ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut

Tags: android, multithreading

When I start my activity ,I get an  ANR error .I not getting how to fixed ,I think this error is because of event.

This is the error:

```
    01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): ANR in com.vxoom.qit.login (com.vxoom.qit.login/.UpdateTokenList)
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): Load: 2.36 / 2.14 / 2.09
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): CPU usage from 24818ms to 0ms ago with 99% awake:
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   3.3% 3575/com.vxoom.qit.login: 2.9% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 939 minor
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 2% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0.6% 477/RTKTHREAD: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0.3% 214/com.android.systemui: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 10 minor
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0.2% 147/system_server: 0.2% user + 0% kernel / faults: 23 minor
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0.1% 85/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0% 133/adbd: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0% 2611/kworker/u:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   0% 3450/kworker/u:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): 7.4% TOTAL: 3.5% user + 3.5% kernel + 0.2% softirq
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): CPU usage from 354ms to 868ms later:
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   2.7% 477/RTKTHREAD: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   1.2% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):   1.9% 147/system_server: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147):     1.9% 179/InputDispatcher: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
01-23 12:29:29.594: E/ActivityManager(147): 7.6% TOTAL: 0% user + 7.6% kernel
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's most probably your fault. Because something was doing a work in the UI thread, touch event couldn't be dispatched. That's why the exception was thrown.

In phone's settings open **Developer options** and enable **Strict mode** (may be named differently), it will help you to find long running operations in main thread.

What triggers ANR:
http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html